# Get table height of DocumentRenderer FormatedDocument in Migradoc

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm creating a PDFSharp document with an embedded table created using Migradoc.
This works just fine.

As the table has a variable number of rows, I need to know the actual height after rendering it into the main PDFsharp document. I need this to continue drawing other sections just after the table created using Migradoc.

This is the code that actually prepares and renders the table:

```
        DocumentRenderer docRenderer = new DocumentRenderer(doc);
        docRenderer.PrepareDocument();
        
        docRenderer.RenderObject(gfx, XUnit.FromPoint(x), XUnit.FromPoint(y), XUnit.FromPoint(width), populatedTable);
```

In the **docRenderer.PrepareDocument().FormatedDocument** I can get the number of pages (in my case will always be one) and the size of the actual page (A4, for example) but not the height of the actual object.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just found out how to do it.

After you call PrepareDocument(), you can access the RenderInfo array and check its content:

```
        RenderInfo[] info = docRenderer.GetRenderInfoFromPage(1);

        double yTableHeight = info[info.Length - 1].LayoutInfo.ContentArea.Height.Point;
```

In my case I'm rendering directly the table to a PDFsharp document, the whole ContentArea height is for the table.  On a normal page, you will have also margins to add to this number.